# Visual Studio how to change GoToDeclaration shortcut (Ctrl+F12)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, declaration, shortcut

In Visual Studio, C#, we have many interfaces. And you want to see a function's implementation and the only way its by pressing **Ctrl+F12**=GoToDeclaration.

The other shortcuts **Ctrl + Left Click** or **F12** will go to the function's definition in the interface. Which is not so used compared to the necessity to see the actual implementation and navigate code.

I highly navigate by clicking names. I know you also do. And the only way is by pressing two keys which is extremely slow especially because when inspecting you usually only use the mouse.

I want to change GoToDeclaration shortcut from **Ctrl + F12** to **Mouse middle button click** (scroll click) and Visual Studio settings allows me only keyboard shortcuts.

[image: Can't assign mouse shortcut]

Comment: Your request is very difficult. Unless you use keymaps, or something else like mouse macros.

Comment: The program Autokey mapper should do the job. When pressing middle mouse click, apply Ctrl+F12. That's good idea.
But still is annoying how can I not assign in VS a mouse shortcut, only keyboard ones. Even JetBrains lets you hold Ctrl + LClick to navigate. Very time consuming from VS.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT If no other answer appears, you can write one just saying to use AutoHotKey program. It can be considered a solution.

Comment: Ok, I did it. Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments:

> A simple workaround to use `middle mouse` button click (scroll click) instead of `Ctrl + F12` for the GoToDeclaration shortcut is to use  `AutoHotKey program`.

```
 ~MButton:: { Send {LButton} Send ^{F12} Return }
```

Comment: @MihaiSocaciu Ok, I did it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact question and created an Autohotkey script with a few improvements.

- It also checks if the current application is Visual Studio
- It also checks if the cursor is over text

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe devenv.exe ; Only apply the hotkey when Visual Studio is active

~MButton::
    If (A_Cursor = "IBeam") ; Only apply the hotkey when the cursor is an I-beam
    {
        Send ^{F12} ; Emulate Ctrl + F12
    }
return

#IfWinActive ; Reset the hotkey condition to any window
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about that IBeam. I also added the verification for Visual Studio, but like this 
```
SetTitleMatchMode 2 ; WinActive will search substrings not full title
...
If (WinActive("Microsoft Visual Studio"))
``` 
And added the script in windows startup 'C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup'.